# If CO2 is nonpolar how come much more dissolves in water than O2?

Tags: solubility, polarity

Why is it that $\ce{CO2}$ is considerably more soluble in water than $\ce{O2}$ is?

$\ce{CO2}$ is nonpolar but dissolves in water which like $\ce{CO2}$ being nonpolar, doesn't make any sense.

Is it the bond polarity and that the bond polarity is more important in solubility?

If not than why is $\ce{CO2}$ more soluble in water than $\ce{O2}$.

Comment: Just because a molecule is non-polar, it does not mean that there are no dipole moments in the molecule. Carbon dioxide has 2 dipole moments in opposite directions and of equal strength (the dipole moment of the molecule is 0; therefore it is non-polar).

Comment: @LDC3 I would say it slightly differently. CO2 has no dipole moment, but that doesn't make it nonpolar. The combined opposed dipole moments give the whole molecule a "quadrupole moment" meaning that if there is a 4-pole electric field with positive at north and south and negative at east and west, the CO2 molecule will tend to turn to a north-south orientation. Larger molecules may have hexapole, octupole or higher moments (with progressively less effect.) CO2's polar bonds enable it to absorb infrared light much more easily than N2 or O2, which is what makes it an important greenhouse gas.

Comment: @steveverrill In collage I was taught that dipole refers to the polarization between 2 bonded atoms, not the molecule. From this definition, $CO_2$ has 2 dipoles (in opposite directions). The net effect results in $CO_2$ being non-polar. A non-polar molecule without any dipoles is oxygen, nitrogen, hydrogen, sulfur ($S_8$), ...

Comment: @LDC3 dipole just means a separation of charges into 2 ends, a positive end and a negative end. Bonds between dissimilar atoms have a dipole. A molecule can also have a dipole. H2O has both. A molecule's "dipole moment" is its quantitative tendency to align itself with an electric field, and tables exist of these. As CO2 has no dipole moment, many textbooks classify it as "non polar" but it does belong to the next group: molecules with quadrupole moments. When discussing solubility, equating dipole moment with "polarity" is not always helpful. For example hexamine is massively soluble in water

Comment: @steveverrill Since a dipole is actually a vector, then I guess that when you sum the vectors, you could still call it  a dipole, although I would call the molecule polarized. I never mentioned anything about solubility in my posts (I'm not familiar enough with that topic). What I was pointing out in my first comment was that not all non-polar molecules are absent of dipole moments.

Comment: let me guess. The quadrupole is from 2 equal dipoles and the hexapole is from 3 equal dipoles

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taken from my answer to your [original question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14641/why-is-o-c-o-nonpolar)

There are a couple of reasons why $\ce{CO2}$ is more soluble in water than $\ce{O2}$.  Because the two $\ce{C=O}$ bonds in $\ce{CO2}$ are polarized (whereas in $\ce{O2}$ the bond is not polarized) it makes it easier for the polar water molecule to solvate it and to form hydrogen bonds.  Both of these factors will stabilize a $\ce{CO2}$ molecule more than an $\ce{O2}$ molecule in water; stabilization translates into greater solubility.  Another factor enhancing the solubility of $\ce{CO2}$ in water is the fact that $\ce{CO2}$ reacts with water to set up an equilibrium with carbonic acid.
$$\ce{CO2(aq) + H2O <=> H2CO3(aq)}$$
This reaction will also enhance $\ce{CO2}$'s solubility in water compared to oxygen which does not react with water.

Comment: This is a good answer because it covers both possibilities - the enhanced solubility due to polarized bonds as well as the reaction of $\ce{CO2}$ with water. I think it is important to note though, that the reaction with water is primarily responsible for the increased solubility. For proof, take a look at the solubility of [$\ce{CO}$ vs. $\ce{CO2}$](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/gases-solubility-water-d_1148.html) - $\ce{CO}$ is polar, but is 60 times **less** soluble than $\ce{CO2}$.

Comment: Good point thomij.  Note, though, that in $\ce{CO2}$ it is the oxygen that is negatively polarized, while in $\ce{CO}$ the oxygen is positively polarized.  I suspect this has a significant effect on hydrogen bonding and, consequently, solvation.  As is so often the case, too many variables, too few experiments.

Comment: @Jori "Both of these factors"  I mean like this...Because the two $\ce{C=O}$ bonds in $\ce{CO2}$ are polarized (whereas in $\ce{O2}$ the bond is not polarized) it makes it **1)**  easier for the polar water molecule to solvate it and **2)** to form hydrogen bonds.  Private communication is fine, give me your e-mail and I'll contact you, or we could use SE Chem chat.

Comment: sent you an e-mail

Comment: why would the oxygen in carbon monoxide have a partially positive charge? That only seems possible for oxygen flourides.

Comment: @caters First off, note that the direction of the experimentally determined dipole moment has the positive center on oxygen (see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_monoxide#Bonding_and_dipole_moment).  Second, draw the resonance structures for CO that have octets.  You should come up with 2, one of which places positive charge on the oxygen (see structures J & K here  http://www.chem.ucla.edu/harding/tutorials/resonance/imp_res_str_key.html).  BTW, if my answer above was helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Doesn't the water induce a dipole in the O2 making O2 more soluble in water than it would be otherwise? and I don't think that where the positive and negative charge is affects H bonding if you compare 2 scenarios where 1 is according to the electronegativity and 1 is opposite. the number of polar bonds, the size of the atoms, and the electronegativity difference are more important factors to consider in H bonding.

Comment: "Doesn't the water induce a dipole in the O2 making O2 more soluble in water than it would be otherwise?"  Yes;  "I don't think that where the positive and negative charge is affects H bonding" I basically agree with that.

Answer (score 2):

That is because $\ce{CO2}$ will react with water in equilibrium to form $\ce{H2CO3}$, which is an acid and thus will dissociate to form ions that can easily fit in the polar solvent (i.e. water). $\ce{O2}$ on the other hand does not react with water because it is not a very good electrophile in comparison to $\ce{CO2}$. The $\pi$-bond is weak in $\ce{CO2}$ (i.e. high in energy), partly because the $\ce{C=O}$ bond is polarized and because of delocalisation in remaining $\pi$-bond of $\ce{CO2}$. $\ce{O2}$ does not have that luxury.

Answer (score 1):

Though the whole molecule has a net dipole moment of zero due to its geometry, the C=O bond has a dipole moment. Compared to the O=O bond which has no dipole moment.

Answer (score 0):

Some folks throw around the formula H2CO3 as if it were a real compound.  The assumption is that it is a weak acid, and thus does not ionize to a great extent.  The truth of the matter is that there are no H2CO3 molecules in aqueous solution.  They don't exist.  What we call "carbonic acid" is CO2 dissolved in water in equilibrium with slight amounts of H+ and HCO3^-.

CO2(aq) + HOH(l) <==> H+ + HCO3^- .............. Ka is small

A small Ka means that the equilibrium lies far to the left, and that almost all of the CO2 stays CO2 and certainly doesn't form molecular H2CO3.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Be sure to read through the tour if you have not done so already.  http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour  I think the asker wants a comparison between CO2 and O2.  O2 is not mentioned at all in this answer.

Comment: You are right but I think carbonic acid makes sense as chemical entity. I repeat, you are right in practical contexts. But if a CO2 molecule and a water one should met in an otherwise empty space I think that the result is carbonic acid, eventually in a similar equilibrium depending on the exact conditions.