# Why does CO2 have higher boiling point than CO?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, boiling-point

The intermolecular forces between $\ce{CO2}$ molecules are dispersion forces, while the forces between $\ce{CO}$ molecules are mostly dipole-dipole attraction forces. So, why does $\ce{CO2}$ have a higher boiling point than that of $\ce{CO}$?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42946/can-nonpolar-molecules-exhibit-dipole-dipole-forces

Comment: I don't think it answers my question.

Comment: There are many other points on the scale from dipole-dipole interaction to dispersion forces. $\ce{CO}$ is a very weak dipole; on the other hand, $\ce{CO2}$ is a pretty strong _quadrupole_.

Comment: > the forces between COCO molecules are mostly dipole-dipole attraction forces.  || Orientation of CO molecules in solid is random with *weak* preference of head-tail. This suggests that dispersion interactions dominates in CO solid.

Comment: Also the MW of $\ce{CO2}$ is about 57% greater than that of $\ce{CO}$ meaning that it will take considerably more energy to raise the kinetic energy of the heavier molecule to where it has the necessary surface escape velocity.

Comment: CO$_2$  does cannot exist at a liquid under standard conditions, but CO can. CO$_2$undergoes sublimation and only exists in liquid form at high pressures so it is inaccurate to compare the boiling points if they are not under the same pressure.

Answer (score 5):

$\ce{CO2}$ has more electrons than $\ce{CO}$. This means that it has a much larger electron cloud as compared to $\ce{CO}$, so its more easily polarised and thus, the ease of forming instataneous dipole-induced dipole bonds increases. Even though $\ce{CO}$ is a polar molecule and it forms permanent dipole-permanent dipole bonds, in this case the id-id bonds are stronger.

P.s. Just a $17 \space year \space old$ A Level Chem student here, I might be wrong

Comment: I believe you are on the right track here. Additionally to your thought, CO2 has a well developed quadrupole moment.

Answer (score 0):

The larger the small covalent molecule, the greater the intermolecular bonds, hence higher boiling / melting point.

$\ce{CO2}$ has 3 atoms involved in the molecule and is therefore larger than $\ce{O2}$ that has 2 atoms. Hence, $\ce{CO2}$ has a higher boiling / melting point compared to $\ce{O2}$. (Exception to this is water molecules.)