# Is there experimental evidence to show boiling point increases with external electric field, and if so, by how much?

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase, intermolecular-forces, boiling-point

I was wondering whether anyone has demonstrated that a liquid will have a higher boiling point if it is placed in a very large electric field. I believe to be the case, since induced dipoles would be formed and dipoles would more heavily align, but I was wondering if there was any actual experimental evidence and how exactly boiling point grows with temperature.

For an order-of-magnitude check, I set up a model to predict the increase in boiling point.

We have the following formulae (considering induced dipoles only):

\begin{align}
U&=-k\frac{p^2}{r^3}N_A\\
p&=\alpha E\\
r&\approx\left(N_A\rho_m\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align}

Which gives

$$U=-k\alpha^2N_A^2E^2\rho_m$$

Given a change in molar density from $\rho_l$ to the ideal gas $\frac{P}{RT}$, we have

$$\Delta U=k\alpha^2N_A^2E^2\left(\rho_l-\frac{P}{RT}\right)=C_p\Delta T_{\text{boiling}}$$

In the case of benzene ([initial boiling point $353.2\,\text{K}$, molar density $11385\,\text{mol m}^{-3}$, specific heat capacity $103\,\text{J mol}^{-1}\text{K}^{-1}$](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/benzene-benzol-properties-d_2053.html), [dielectric strength $163\,\text{MV m}^{-1}$](https://chemistry.mdma.ch/hiveboard/rhodium/pdf/chemical-data/diel_strength.pdf), [polarizability $69.6\text{Å}^3$](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Molecular-Polarizabilities-in-au-3-Determined-from-Atomic-Dipolar-Polarizabilities_tbl1_228358308)), my model would give a maximum $\Delta U$ of [$59.0\,\text{J mol}^{-1}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coulomb+constant*%28avogadros+constant%5E2*%2869.6+angstrom%5E3%2Fcoulombs+constant%29%5E2*%28.163+GV%2Fm%29%5E2*%2811385mol%2Fm%5E3+-+standard+pressure%2F%28gas+constant*%28273.15%2B80%29K%29) before dielectrib breakdown, or $\Delta T_{\text{boiling}}$ of [$0.522\,\text{K}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coulomb+constant*%28avogadros+constant%5E2*%2869.6+angstrom%5E3%2Fcoulombs+constant%29%5E2*%28.163+GV%2Fm%29%5E2*%2811385mol%2Fm%5E3+-+standard+pressure%2F%28gas+constant*%28273.15%2B80%29K%29%29%2F%28113+J%2F%28K+mol%29%29), something that should be measurable. My model probably doesn't take into account a lot of things, but I'm sure that the actual maximum change in boiling point should only be half an order of magnitude away from my estimate hopefully.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60289/in-practice-do-polar-molecules-actually-align-in-an-electric-field

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/108577/molecule-with-a-quadrupole-moment-in-an-electric-field